# Remove item from collection defined in ViewModel from click event in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, mvvm

I have an ItemsControl populated with items defined in a DataTemplate and placed on a Canvas. I would like to be able to use a right-click event on one of these items on the Canvas to remove it from the containing collection, which is in my ViewModel. I have been trying to work with MVVM Light's EventToCommand to figure out a way but so far I've come up with nothing. I don't know what else to try, so I come to SO for help. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Player}">
        <Canvas>               
            <Grid Canvas.Left="{Binding Location.X}"
                  Canvas.Top="{Binding Location.Y}"
                  MouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                  MouseLeftButtonUp="Grid_MouseLeftButtonUp"
                  MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove">
                <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <Ellipse Width="12"
                         Height="12" 
                         Fill="{Binding PrimaryColor}" />
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="6"
                           FontWeight="Bold"
                           Foreground="Black"
                           Text="{Binding Position.Abbreviation}" />
            </Grid>
        </Canvas>
    </DataTemplate>

<Canvas x:Name="myCanvas"
        Width="1440"
        Height="640"
        AllowDrop="True"
        Background="Green"
        Focusable="True">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Field}" />
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Team.Players}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas AllowDrop="True" Background="Transparent" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: you want to  have a contextmenu with delete option on right click  to delete a particular item?

Comment: Either a single right-click or a contextmenu would work. A contextmenu would actually probably serve me better in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `ContextMenu` with Remove `MenuItem`. Then you can have `Command` `RemoveCommand` on your `ViewModel`. You can bind `MenuItem` Command to VM command like below and send the Selected Item in the `CommandParameter`. In Command handler you can remove that item from the collection.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Player}">
    <Canvas>               
        <Grid Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}} Canvas.Left="{Binding Location.X}"
              Canvas.Top="{Binding Location.Y}"
              MouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown"
              MouseLeftButtonUp="Grid_MouseLeftButtonUp"
              MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove">
            <Grid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Remove" 
                         Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.RemoveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" 
                         CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, 
          RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
          AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
            </Grid.ContextMenu>
            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <Ellipse Width="12"
                     Height="12" 
                     Fill="{Binding PrimaryColor}" />
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="6"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Foreground="Black"
                       Text="{Binding Position.Abbreviation}" />
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
</DataTemplate>
```